# bootstrap validator validation on dynamically added combobox

Tags: javascript, php, validation, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I have a form with two comboboxes.The 2nd combobox is initially with options of empty value.Values for 2nd combobox are added dynamically according to value of 1st combobox through a php script in another file,that computes values for 2nd one from db.
I ve used innerhtml method to replace the combobox with the html in php.
Now bootstrap validator not recognizing the change in value of the second combobox,when selected.It assumes the value of the 2nd one to be empty.
How to make it scan again after adding values?

```
<!--main.html-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Degree Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="dtype" onChange="display(this.value)" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Type --</option>
            <option value="UG">UG</option>
            <option value="PG">PG</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name of the Department</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="show_dept">
            <select name="dept" class="form-control">
                <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Dept --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Validation-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tryitForm').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh',
                submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
                    // Use Ajax to submit form data
                    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
                        // ... process the result ...
                    }, 'json');
                }
            },
            fields: {
                dept: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Department cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<!--Ajax-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // JavaScript Document
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

    function display(dept_type) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("show_dept").innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            }
        }
        XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "get_dept.php?dept_type=" + dept_type, true);
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send();
    }
</script>


<!--get_dept.php-->
<?php 
    $con=mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '') or die( 'Mysql not connected'); 
    mysql_select_db( 'db',$con) or die( 'DataBase not connected'); 
    $dtype=$_REQUEST[ 'dept_type']; 
    $query="select * from dept_mast where Deg_Type='$dtype'" ; 
?>
<select name="dept" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Dept --</option>
    <?php 
        $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error(); 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row[ 'Dept_Name']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row[ 'Dept_Name']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: welcome to SO, you should show us some code to help you.

Comment: @code-jaff i ve given the code segments

Answer (score 0):

It's redundant to define and use custom ajax handler since you are using jQuery.

let's try this way,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    $('#tryitForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh',
            submitHandler: function (validator, form, submitButton) {
                // Use Ajax to submit form data
                $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function (result) {
                    // ... process the result ...
                }, 'json');
            }
        },
        fields: {
            dept: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Department cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    validate();
});

function display(dept_type) {
    $.get('get_dept.php', {
        dept_type: dept_type
    }, function (response) {
        $("#show_dept").empty().html(response);
        validate();
    });
}
</script>
```

since you are attaching the form control on the fly, the validator doesn't know about the new element. You need to call the validator again to tell that you have added some new elements to validate.

Comment: thanks the reduced form of the function 'display' is nice...but validation not working still.Also 'fields' is within function bootstrapvalidator,so it should not be ended with }); but with } otherwise not working...

Comment: i found that once the function validate is invoked on document ready,it kind of forms lock. It is not overrided when called again in function display...but when i removed it from document ready and make it invoke only on display function,it works as is to be...any way to FLUSH the function validate and call it again?